# Can I use PHP built-in webserver to run simple CGI scripts on localhost?

Tags: php, database, webserver, key-value, bookmarklet

I can run a simple built-in webserver with command "php -S localhost:8001"
I find it very simple and useful for creating bookmarklets for the browser, as .js files.
Now I would like to know if it is able to run CGI scripts too? I should maintain a simple key-value database from the javascript code of the bookmarklet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't.

You could probably write a wrapper around a CGI program in PHP, but it would be easier to use a more suitable webserver.